# Problema al descargar archivos adjuntos

Tags: c#, asp.net

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación en **C#** con ayuda de **ASP.NET**, en la cual estoy adjuntando algunos archivos a la información de un requerimiento, no tengo problema al cargar los archivos esto lo hace sin ningún inconveniente, el problema esta al momento de descargar dichos archivos, cuando se intenta descargar el archivo solamente se refresca la pagina sin descargar nada.

A continuación adjunto el código **HTML** de mi formulario que me permite adjuntar los archivos, dejo claro que es el mismo formulario para la carga y la descarga del archivo.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="card shadow mb-4">
                        <div class="card-header py-3">
                            <h4 class="m-0 font-weight-bold text-primary">Archivos Adjuntos</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <div class="mb-4">
                                <div class="form-group" id="LoadedFiles"></div>
                                <form enctype="multipart/form-data" name="fileUpload" method="post">
                                    <input type="file" name="files" id="file" onchange="validateFiles()" multiple>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

**Index.cshtml**

```
@using System.Web.Configuration
@{
    //hay numero de ticket -> consulta ticket
    if (ViewBag.TicketNumber != null)
    {
        @Html.Hidden("loadedFiles", Url.Action("LoadFiles"))
        @Html.Hidden("download", Url.Action("DownloadFile"))
    }

}

<div class="card shadow mb-4">
    <div class="card-header py-3">
          <h4 class="m-0 font-weight-bold text-primary">Archivos Adjuntos</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
            <div class="mb-4">
                <div class="form-group" id="LoadedFiles"></div>
                    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" name="fileUpload" method="post">
                        <input type="file" name="files" id="file" onchange="validateFiles()" multiple>
                    </form>
            </div>
        </div>
 </div>
```

Función **javascript** para la carga de los archivos

**LoadData.js**

```
function loadFiles() {
    const url = document.getElementById("loadedFiles").value;
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {

            for (let idx in data) {
                if (data.hasOwnProperty(idx)) {
                    $("#LoadedFiles")
                        .append(
                            `<p><button class="downloadBtn" onclick="download('${idx}')">${data[idx]}</button></p>`);
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Metodo en el controlador para la carga de archivos

**TicketFormController.cs**

```
[HttpPost]
        public JsonResult LoadFiles()
        {
            using (var files = new FileController())
            {
                return Json(files.GetFtpContents(Convert.ToInt64(TempData.Peek("ticketNumber"))));
            }
        }
```

**Se intento:**

Para poder descargar el archivo adjunto la única forma es presionando control 
+ click pero esto lo que hace es abrir una nueva pestaña en el navegador y permite descargar el archivo.

Existirá alguna forma de descargar el archivo directo.

**Actualización:**

```
/// <summary>
        ///     Obtiene el archivo para descargar
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="info">Direccion del archivo a descargar</param>
        /// <returns>Archivo solicitado para la descarga</returns>
        [HttpGet]
        public FileResult DownloadFile(string info)
        {
            using (var files = new FileController())
            {
                return files.DownloadFtpFile(Convert.ToInt64(TempData.Peek("ticketNumber")), info);
            }
        }
```

**Actualización 2:**

```
/// <summary>
        ///     Obtiene el archivo para ser enviado directamente como descarga
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="ticketId">Id del ticket al que le pertenece el archivo</param>
        /// <param name="path">/[sequence]/[nombre archivo]</param>
        /// <returns>Archivo solicitado para descarga</returns>
        public FileResult DownloadFtpFile(long ticketId, string path)
        {
            using (var request = new WebClient())
            {

                request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(_ftpUser, _ftpPass);


                var fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(path)?.Replace(".", "");

                if (fileExtension == null || fileExtension.IsEmpty() || !MimeTypes.ContainsKey(fileExtension))
                    return null; //se subio un archivo que no esta permitido

                var mimeType = MimeTypes[fileExtension];
                var filePath = Path.Combine(_ftpUrl, "tickets", ticketId.ToString(), path);

                try
                {
                   // return File(request.DownloadFile(filePath), mimeType, Path.GetFileName(path)); 

                    return File(request.DownloadData(filePath), mimeType, Path.GetFileName(path));


                }
                catch (WebException ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("ERROR DownloadFtpFile: " + ex.Message);

                    return null;
                }

            }
        }
```

**Actualización 3:**

```
function download(info) {
    const url = document.getElementById("download").value;
    window.location = url + "?info=" + encodeURIComponent(info);
};
```

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101339/discussion-between-sebastian-salazar-and-fredyfx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si entiendo bien, el siguiente código te será de utilidad:

Consideraré que la URL está bien hecha y la descarga funciona bien en caso se abre en una nueva pestaña.

Html:

```
<div id="magicframe" style="display:none;"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
function download(info){           
    var urlBase = document.getElementById("download").value;
    var urlCompleta = urlBase + "?info=" + encodeURIComponent(info);

    //Aqui verifico si existe el elemento 
    //y de ser cierto, elimino dicho elemento 
    //para evitar posibles errores.
    var existeArchivoDiv = $("#DescargarArchivo").length > 0;
    if (existeArchivoDiv) {
       $("#DescargarArchivo").remove();
    }

    //Aqui está la magia: Solucionado con un iframe y jQuery con su método load
    $("<iframe />", { id: "DescargarArchivo"}).attr("src", urlCompleta).appendTo('#magicframe');

    //Utiliza el siguiente código en caso tengas que ejecutar algo una vez que el archivo se descargue
    //$("#DescargarArchivo").load(function () {
        //Aqui puedes colocar algo en caso tengas que esperar a que el usuario tenga el archivo.              
    //});
}
```