# Mostrar animacion y deshabilitar Boton dureante la descarga, y habilitar despues de la respuesta del controlador

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net, mvc, asp.net-core

Estoy trabajando sobre .net y en uno de los controller tengo un Return File, la secuencia es la siguiente yo envió la petición con un botón ya que cuando le doy click este envía una petición al controller el cual me retorna el File, me gustaría saber si existe la posibilidad de que cuando se haga el return file yo pueda indicarle a la vista que ya termino el proceso.

el proceso anterior lo deseo hacer ya que deseo sobreponer un gif a la vista cuando se oprima el botón y se quite cuando el controller me devuelva el archivo, agradezco su ayuda con respecto a este tema.

Controller(Return File):

```
return File(resultFinally, "application/vnd.ms-excel", fileNameAlone + "_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd") + "_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss") + extension);
```

html:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Upload", "UploadFile", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
        {
            <div class="row">
                <label for="file" class="col-1" align="right">File:</label>
                <input type="file" id="file" name="file" class="form-control-file col-11" onchange="return fileValidation()">
            </div>
            <br />
            <div id="lblError" style="color:red; font-family:Bahnschrift; font-size: 16px;">
                @Html.Raw(@ViewBag.msgError)
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
                <div id="msgError" style="color:red; font-size:16px; font-family:Bahnschrift;"></div>
                <div id="msgErrorValid" style="color:green; font-size:16px; font-family:Bahnschrift;"></div>
                <div class="col-12">
                    <button disabled="disabled" id="btnUpload" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="disableButton()">Upload File</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        }
```

Comment: Agrega el codigo que llevas, y a que te refieres con controlar descarga 'directa' desde chrome y al mismo tiempo desde tu servidor.

Comment: te puse el retur en la edicion de la pregunta, sin embargo el tema es que cuando yo envio el comando pulsando el boton el controller me descarga un archivo sin embargo el se demora en el proceso y yo quiero sobreponer un gif cuando el esta haciendo el proceso en el controller y que se quite cuando llegue al return file

Comment: Revisa este escenario https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/310223/822 tiene mucha similitud con tu caso

Comment: ¿La respuesta a esta pregunta solucionó tu problema? Si es así, por favor, marca la respuesta como correcta haciendo uso del icono de marca (**✔**) que hay a su lado. ¿Sigues necesitando ayuda con este tema? Entonces responde a este comentario para que le eche un vistazo.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes enviar un parametro al servidor y esperar que ese mismo parametro este contenido
en la respuesta del servidor cuando el archivo se haya descargado.

```
//en tu codigo solo agregue "descargando..." mientras se descarga el archivo lo puedes cambiar por otro elemento


// @Html.Hidden("cookieDescarga") este campo guarda el valor enviado al servidor nos servira para saber cuando el servidor responda.
//En donde se actualiza el texto del boton lo puedes cambiar por una animacion


    //archivo vista:
    <script>
        var _tmr;
        $(function () {
            $('#btnUpload').click(function () {

                $('#cookieDescarga').val(Date.now().toString());

                // se actualiza el valor del boton
                 $('#btnUpload').val("descargando");


                // inicia la espera para que el servidor responda
                _tmr = window.setInterval(function () {
                    var _str = 'dlc=' + $('#cookieDescarga').val();
                    if (document.cookie.indexOf(_str) !== -1) {

                          //se actualiza el valor del boton  
                            $('#btnUpload').val("upload file");
                    }
                }, 100);
            });
        });
    </script>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Upload", "UploadFile", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
            {
                  @Html.Hidden("cookieDescarga")
                <div class="row">
                    <label for="file" class="col-1" align="right">File:</label>
                    <input type="file" id="file" name="file" class="form-control-file col-11" onchange="return fileValidation()">
                </div>
                <br />
                <div id="lblError" style="color:red; font-family:Bahnschrift; font-size: 16px;">
                    @Html.Raw(@ViewBag.msgError)
                </div>
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <div id="msgError" style="color:red; font-size:16px; font-family:Bahnschrift;"></div>
                    <div id="msgErrorValid" style="color:green; font-size:16px; font-family:Bahnschrift;"></div>
                    <div class="col-12">
                        <button disabled="disabled" id="btnUpload" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="disableButton()">Upload File</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            }


    //para el controlador debes aceptar el parametro cookieDescarga basicamente es un timestamp.
    //en tu controlador:


         UploadFile(,,,tus parametros, string cookieDescarga) {


          //como puedes ver simplemente se agrega el mismo parametro enviado por el cliente
          //de esta manera el cliente identifica que el servidor respodio cuando el archivo
           // se haya descargado.


               ControllerContext.HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie("dlc", cookieDescarga));

            return File(resultFinally, "application/vnd.ms-excel", fileNameAlone + "_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd") + "_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss") + extension);

}
```